# Write on two different worksheets dosen't work excel 2007

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, worksheet

I have a problem, I need to write some information on an excel.

I can write correctly on one of the two worksheets ("worksheet"), and with the other ("worksheet2"), it doesn't write anything and I don't know why. All the process is the same but it doesn't write anything.

I put my code below, hope it helps:

```
var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Workbooks.Open(destFile);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = excelApp.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet2 = excelApp.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        excelApp.Visible = false;

        var data = new object[numRows, numColumns];
        int contadorMedidas = 0;
        //int primeraVez = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++)  // assuming the data starts at 1,1
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= numColumns; j++)
            {
                if (contadorMedidas < contents.Count)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i, j] = contents[contadorMedidas];
                    contadorMedidas++;
                }
            }
        }

        //Escribir en la hoja de pautas el nombre y los valores de codigo y plano
        //Codigo
        worksheet2.Cells[2, 5] = codigo;
        //Plano
        worksheet2.Cells[3, 4] = plano;
        //Trabajador
        worksheet2.Cells[6, 2] = cbxWorker.Text;
        //Si es BR, hay que añadir un código extra:
        if (br)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
            {
                worksheet2.Cells[8 + i, 6] = "7525SI-0203-FA"; 
            }
        }

        excelApp.Quit();
```

Comment: What does your excel look like when opened like this, does it have the appropriate amount of worksheets? Perhaps you first need to add a worksheet?

Comment: I make a copy of an excel that has this two pages and one more. One is called "Pauta", other "Medidas" and the last one "Filtros".

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your code when it is going to write in the worksheet2, you have a condition. Maybe this condition is false, which is why it is not writing to worksheet2.

```
if (br)
{
    //write to worksheet2
}
```

Otherwise, I used the following code and was able to write on both worksheets that are in the same Excel workbook.
Hope this helps.

```
//I created a class called ExcelFunctions which has the 
//methods OpenExcelFile and AccessSpecificExcelSheet
var excelFunction = new ExcelFunctions();    

//Open the Excel file
excelWorkbook = excelFunction.OpenExcelFile(excelApp, excelFilePath);

//Get the sheets
Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

//Access the first sheet
string sheetName = "Sheet1";
Worksheet activeWorksheet = excelFunction.AccessSpecificExcelSheet(excelSheets, sheetName);
                activeWorksheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Write to sheet1";

//Access the second sheet
string sheetName2 = "Sheet2";
activeWorksheet = excelFunction.AccessSpecificExcelSheet(excelSheets, sheetName2);
activeWorksheet.Cells[4, 1] = "Write to sheet2";
```

This is what my "AccessSpecificationExcelSheet" method looks like:

```
public Worksheet AccessSpecificExcelSheet(Sheets allExcelSheets, string sheetName)
{
    Worksheet selectedWorksheet = allExcelSheets.get_Item(sheetName);
    selectedWorksheet.Select();

    //Select cell A1 when opening
    Range topExcel = selectedWorksheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);
    topExcel.Select();

    return selectedWorksheet;
}
```

This is what my "OpenExcelFile" method looks like:

```
public Workbook OpenExcelFile(Application excelApp, string excelFilePath)
{
    Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath);
    return excelWorkbook;
}
```

Comment: i can't use OpenExcelFile, why?

Comment: I can get it with " Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(destFile);" but it doesn't work, it gives that error: "Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))"

Comment: @Imrik, Sorry, OpenExcelFile method is a method I define. I have edited the above to show what my OpenExcelFile method does.

Comment: @Imrik With the error you are having, first check that the file you are opening exists and that it isn't currently open. Then check if the sheet you are trying to access exists in the workbook that you opened because the error "DISP_E_BADINDEX' seems like it's about trying to access for example an index in an array that does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, I know what the error means, but I don't know why I have this issue. I try with exit() and close() functions before opening the second sheet and I have the same error one more time. The sheet and the document exist, and they are close before accesing on it.